# WPF dataset/database row edit in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, database, data-binding, datagrid

I know that there is a lot of questions about databinding in WPF C# but I'm already out of my mind.

There is a simple way to do a databinding to a dataGrid in wpf, it is a built-in feature.
But I want to click on the particular row, then click edit button and edit this row and some additional info in new popup window, not into datagrid itself.

Selecting particular row is a other story but now the main problem for me is to load data from this particular row in database to textboxes in new window.
I can do this by

```
  DataTable obj = contactsTableAdapter.GetOne(id);
     DataRow r = obj.Rows[0];
     String sur = r[5].ToString();
```

but this is wrong and one way solution.

I want to use a proper databinding between this selected row and my textboxes, where the user can modify data and click button to call Update method to propagate changes to database.

I'm not sure how to load that particular selected row, to what type of object, and how to bind it to textbox, and how to do this in a clean way, without doing some hacks.

I'm pretty sure that c# provides some obvious solution but I have lost my way somewhere.

I'm waiting for some help impatiently, and thanks for any solution!

Comment: Data binding is so much easier using MVVM. Its a big topic but will save you a lot of pain in the long run. MVVM light toolkit is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MVVM here is a simple solution.

1. Your button click method should have access to datagrid

   ```
   MyItemType item = (MyItemType)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
   ```
2. Pass the item to your new form\window\whaterver.

NOTE: You might want to null check the selecteditem.  You can put the edit buttons in your DataGrid Row.

Comment: That's kind of solution but it covers only half of my problem, it will bind the data that is showed in dtatagrid but any additional data (detailed view - I guess) have to be loaded and bound so the path from database to textBox is still unknown for me. I have already started learning MVVM so maybe that will help me. Thanks for Your answer.